# Swift creating grid of many text fields?

Tags: swift, user-interface, uiviewcontroller

Fairly new to swift and just getting into the design/app making aspect of it. So I want to make a 9X9 grid of text fields for a sudoku solving app, where each text field will take in a number and assign the value to a struct I have created. I am having a hard time finding the correct way to do this. I feel like I could just make 81 text boxes and assign each of them seperately, but I feel like as a programmer this is definitely the wrong way to go about this. Could anyone point me in the right direction?

Thanks!

Comment: I think you can use UICollectionView for this, it is something you could use to create table, calendar, etc..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UICollectionView is the way to go.

If you want a 9*9 grid with a header cell on top then something like this would work:

```
func numberOfSectionsInCollectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 82
}

func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGSize {
    if indexPath.row == 0
    {
        return CGSize(width: screenWidth, height: screenWidth/3)
    }
    return CGSize(width: screenWidth/9, height: screenWidth/9);

}
```

That gives you:

[image]

Complete viewController with an embedded UICollectionView:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout,   UICollectionViewDataSource {


var collectionView : UICollectionView?  // Optional
var screenSize : CGRect!
var screenWidth : CGFloat!
var screenHeight : CGFloat!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    screenSize = self.view.frame

    screenWidth = screenSize.width
    screenHeight = screenSize.height

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    let layout: UICollectionViewFlowLayout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
    layout.sectionInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 20, left: 0, bottom: 10, right: 0)
    layout.itemSize = CGSize(width: screenWidth/3, height: screenWidth/3)
    layout.minimumInteritemSpacing = 0
    layout.minimumLineSpacing = 0
    collectionView = UICollectionView(frame: self.view.frame, collectionViewLayout: layout)
    print(collectionView?.frame.width)
    collectionView!.dataSource = self
    collectionView!.delegate = self
    collectionView!.registerClass(CollectionViewCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "CollectionViewCell")
    collectionView!.backgroundColor = UIColor.greenColor()
    self.view.addSubview(collectionView!)
}

func numberOfSectionsInCollectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 82
}

func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGSize {
    if indexPath.row == 0
    {
        return CGSize(width: screenWidth, height: screenWidth/3)
    }
    return CGSize(width: screenWidth/9, height: screenWidth/9);

}

func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("CollectionViewCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! CollectionViewCell
    if indexPath.row == 0
    {
        cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.lightGrayColor()

    }else
    {
        cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
    }
    cell.layer.borderColor = UIColor.blackColor().CGColor
    cell.layer.borderWidth = 0.5

    //cell.textLabel?.text = "\(indexPath.section):\(indexPath.row)"
    return cell
}

}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! How are you getting the cells to appear? Mine is just a blank screen with whatever color I set the collection view too

Comment: I've added the full code for a view controller with an embedded collection view also shows how to register a custom collection view cell - I guess you will have some very sudoku specific ideas on that.